# Is there a way to format erb files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formatting

I'm searching for a plugin (Sublime Text, Eclipse, Notepad, ...) to format erb files. I've searched a while and haven't found anything that's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
vim file.html.erb
:set ft=html 
gg=G
```

This would ignore erb tags though, for a better support of those, get the [Rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) plugin and `set ft=eruby`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few vim plugins, however they do not work well.

I then tried https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier, a gem that you can execute to format erb files. It has a much better success rate dealing with complex erb files. If it doesn't work (which I have encountered once), then it is probably you missing a closing